# How should I go about making "tutorial hands" to show users how to interact with objects?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm making a game in which players will need to interact with several types of controls (switches, knobs, etc.) in various different ways. For part of the tutorial, I want to show them how to interact with this by showing a disembodied ghost hand interacting with the controls. Essentially, I need the trigger a pose animation on a ghost hand in world space. Any ideas or suggestions on where to start looking?

I've tried using the "Ghost Hand" component, but I couldn't get it to work. It was hard to find any documentation on it either. I may be using it wrong, or it may not be supported.

I'm using Unity 3D with the Oculus Interaction SDK with a Quest 2 for hand tracking. I have hand models already, the ghost hands included with the Oculus SDK. I've tried making a copy of these hands and animating them with the Unity Animator, but it seems like animating the bone children doesn't actually change the visual of the hand.

What I've been trying to do is to just get a ghost hand to move its index finger like its flipping a switch. Ideally this could be triggered by a script.